# Onclick on a ListView with a scrollable item layout does'nt work

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

i have an xml layout that i want to use in 2 cases:
1- for listView item in the adapter (without scroll in a row)
2- for another activity (with a scroll)

I've tried to make this layout Scrollable ( scrollView on the parent)
- when it your for listView item ( disacle the scroll effect)
- when it used for the other activity, enable the scrollView
But when  i make this solution, i can't have the onClickListner on the listView item.

my xml file: list_messages_fragment_item.xml

```
<ScrollView 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:background="@color/light_gray_2"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
  android:paddingRight="10dp"
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
  isScrollContainer="false"   
>

-- My One chlid LinearLayout containing my content 

</ScrollView>
```

this Xml file is  the adapter of my listView: (no need to scroll in this case)

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_messages_fragment_item, null);
```

....

```
}
```

this xml file is  used also for an activity layout: (need scroll in this case)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.list_messages_fragment_item);
```

....

```
}
```

Comment: Please add code in detail

Comment: And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: i have an xml layout that i want to use in 2 cases:
1- for listView item in the adapter (without scroll in a row)
2- for another activity (with a scroll)

I've tried to make this layout Scrollable ( scrollView on the parent)
- when it your for listView item ( disacle the scroll effect)
- when it used for the other activity, enable the scrollView
But when  i make this solution, i can't have the onClickListner on the listView item.

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution for what i want.
i use a LinearLayout parent in my xml file.
i create an other layour for the activity: this layout contains a ScrollView, inside i include my xml file that i want to re-use.
 the new layout to use in the activity:

```
<ScrollView 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/white"
  android:paddingTop="10dp"
  android:paddingLeft="10dp"
  android:paddingRight="10dp"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:scrollbars="none">

   <include layout="@layout/list_messages_fragment_item"/>
  </ScrollView>
```

list_messages_fragment_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@color/light_gray_2"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
>
```

...... my Layout content

```
</LinearLayout>
```